# Кавычки при "как сегодня сказали бы"

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

> Нужно учесть, что купцы в те времена были люди на редкость
>   рисковы**е(,) и** рисковали они не только собранным капиталом, но
>   собственной жизнью. Обладали они и редкими знаниями: языков и
>   географии, а чтобы передвигаться по морю, лесам или пескам пустыни,
>   пользовались наукой математикой – расстояния высчитывались по звёздам,
>   а значит, изучали они и астрономию (тогда – астрологию). Они были
>   посвящены и в тайны многих ремёсел. **А ещё обладали навыками
>   настоящего, как сегодня сказали бы – экстремального путешественника.**

Вопрос к обрамлению етово экстремального путешественника в конце и возможной запятой перед "и рисковали" (причём?) в начале.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Нужно учесть, что **купцы** в те времена **были люди** на редкость **рисковые**,  и **рисковали они** не только собранным капиталом, но собственной жизнью. Запятая в ССП.

2) А ещё обладали навыками настоящего, **как сегодня сказали бы – экстремального**, путешественника.

Думаю, что запятую поставить надо.

Второе определение в этом случае является **занимает позицию** пояснительного (уточняющего) определения и обособляется.

Конструкция содержит дополнительные сведения и имеет сложную структуру, она по содержанию и форме ближе к вставной, но обособляется запятыми в связи с наличием союза КАК.

**Другой вариант (по Розенталю).**

А ещё обладали навыками настоящего или, **как сегодня сказали бы,** экстремального путешественника.

Определения здесь являются однородными.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122
4) Я присмотрелся, попривык к окружающим меня явлениям или, вернее сказать, чудесам природы (Акс.);

Comment: А вот туточки: *А ещё обладали навыками настоящего или, как сегодня сказали бы, экстремального путешественника* - запятая перед **или** не напрашивается? О_о

Comment: А туточки такое дело. Союз ИЛИ считается  соединительным,  так как члены предложения мыслятся однородными. Например: Мы познакомились с соседями или, вернее, с соседками. Мы подбираем более точное слово, но ведь соседи - это не соседки, тождества нет. А пояснительный союз ИЛИ используется, когда один и тот же предмет (признак) имеет два названия. Настоящий и экстремальный - это не одно и то же. Мы опять же подбираем более удачное название, вот и нет запятой.

Comment: Думу буду думати...

Comment: Тема вообще-то смутная. Посмотрите Розенталя п.2 http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119

Answer (score 1):

Нужно учесть, что купцы в те времена были люди на редкость рисковые ***и(что)*** рисковали они не только собранным капиталом, но собственной жизнью.

**Однородные придаточные. Запятая не нужна.**

А ещё обладали навыками настоящего, как сегодня сказали бы **– экстремального путешественника.**

**Как сегодня сказали бы -** вводная конструкция со значением пояснения. Пунктуационное оформление зависит от структуры предложения. В данном случае лучше оформить  при помощи тире. Так как  **"экстремального путешественника"** является обособленным определением, стоящим в конце предложения. В таких случаях обычно ставится тире.

Comment: Сержик, сейчас читаю по второй корректуре - об это же место споткнулась. Не прав ты с запятой, это не однородные придаточные. *Рисковые, причём рисковали они...* А вторая правка - как Шарончик велит, ибо: *...обладали навыками настоящего путешественника, как сегодня сказали бы – экстремального.* Спасибо тебе за старания!